# PL SQL Find repeat events within a time period

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, common-table-expression, window-functions

Thanks in advance.

I have a table with the following schema

```
CallNotes (
Policy    VARCHAR2(15 BYTE)
Notes_TS  TIMESTAMP(6)
UserId    VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
)
```

The granularity of this table is a record for each event occuring on a call.  To identify repeat calls, I need to look for the next timestamp with the same Policy, but a different userid that occurred between 10 minutes and 7 days into the future.  Anything that occurrs after 7 days would be a new call.

Policy and UserID may be repeated with a new note_ts, e.g.:

```
Policy   |Notes_TS                 |UserId
123abc   |2014-11-14 10:10:05.000  |joe
123abc   |2014-11-14 10:11:32.000  |joe
123abc   |2014-11-14 10:11:55.000  |joe
156def   |2014-11-14 10:15:16.000  |julie
123abc   |2014-11-14 10:23:42.000  |jane
```

So, 123abc called in twice, since it is a repeated policy with a different userid that is more than 10 minutes in the future.

I intended to use CTEs and window functions to accomplish this, but I cannot get the first step worked out.

My query looked something like this and I have tried variations of the partitioning, however, I'm just not thinking right about the problem.

```
With orderedCalls as 
    ( Select 
        Policy,
        UserId,
        Notes_TS NewCallTime,
        lag(Notes_TS,1,'01-JAN-1900') over (partition by Policy, UserId order by Notes_TS) prev_ts,
        lead(Notes_TS,1,'01-JAN-1900') over (partition by Policy, UserId order by Notes_TS) prev_ts
        row_number() over(partition by Policy order by Notes_ts) "Order"
      From CallHistory),
  RepeatCalls as 
    (.....
```

I also was considering getting row ordering by both policy and by policy, userid and using that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `lag()` function to get information about the timestamp of the previous call:

```
select cn.*,
       (case when prev_userid <> userid and
                  notes_ts - prev_ts between '+00 00:10:00' and '+07 00:00:00'
              then 1 else 0 end) as IsRepeat
from (select cn.*,
             lag(Notes_ts) over (partition by Policy order by Notes_ts) as prev_ts,
             lag(userid) over (partition by Policy order by Notes_ts) as prev_userid
      from CallNotes cn
     ) cn;
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is great, except that it grabs the next entry, rather than the next entry from a different user.  I edited my question with example data.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @StephenLloyd . . . It grabs the next entry and then checks whether or not it is from the same user.  This still sounds like what you want to do, and it would pick up the third row in your example table.

Comment: Indeed.  Thanks.  I was thinking in the wrong direction.  Looks good so far.